# Intermittent connectivity drops from SSMS (from Azure Data science VM) to Azure Sql Database

Tags: azure, networking, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-virtual-network

I am connecting to my Azure sql database from SSMS hosted on Azure Data science virtual machine. I am experiencing frequent connectivity drops to Azure SQL database.

I have observed the below pattern when the connectivity breaks:

1. Idle for 2-3 minutes on SSMS
2. Alt+Tab to different window and back to SSMS
3. Working for longer time

The DSVM is joined to our client's domain and we connect to it via Citrix. Please provide any suggestions to fix the intermittent connectivity issue.

Below are the details of some troubleshooting that I have done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any update on your side?

Comment: The issue is intermittent, we have installed WireShark and asked the user to perform a packet capture when the issue occurs. Surprisingly, the user is able to resolve the name from the DSVM now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a DNS resolution issue as you can read on the first screen you shared with us. It seems you have intermittent DNS name resolution.

Open a command prompt window and use the PING command to confirm that name resolution successfully translates your logical server name to an IP address. The “Request timed out” message shown below is expected because SQL Database will never respond to ping requests.

```
C:\>ping <myserver>.database.windows.net
Pinging data.sn1-1.database.windows.net [65.55.74.144] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Ping statistics for 65.55.74.144:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

If this step fails intermittently, contact your network administrator, your Citrix Administrator or Internet service provider for assistance with fixing your name resolution problem.

Next, from your command prompt window, try to telnet to port 1433 using the IP address returned in the prior step. This will test whether there are any firewalls/routers blocking traffic to port 1433.

```
C:\>telnet 65.55.74.144 1433

Connecting To 65.55.74.144...
```

a.If Telnet is successful, the window will change to a completely blank screen. Exit and proceed to the next step.
b.If it is not successful, capture the output and provide it to your network administrator or Citrix administrator along with the tracert output..

Next, from your command prompt window, repeat the test by trying to telnet to the DNS name instead of the IP address.

```
C:\>telnet <myserver>.database.windows.net 1433
```

Note: If Telnet is not part of your default windows installation, you may enable it from Add/Remove Windows Components.

Finally, to isolate network problems, generate a Network Trace using Microsoft Network Monitor tool like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh451296(v=vs.85)) one.

Review the trace by adding a filter TCP.port==1433 which would show conversations on TCP port 1433. If you do not see an ACK back from the server, it is highly likely that the connection is blocked on your network or over the internet.

A network snippet from a connection that was not successful:

```
11:12:27.007      25   {TCP:7, IPv4:6}  111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   TCP        TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49411, DstPort=1433, PayloadLen=0, Seq=2375502765, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
11:12:30.007 26 {TCP:7, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #25]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49411, DstPort=1433, PayloadLen=0, Seq=2375502765, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192 11:12:36.007 29 {TCP:7, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #25]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49411, DstPort=1433, PayloadLen=0, Seq=2375502765, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 819211:12:48.014      40   {TCP:12, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   TCP        TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49412, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=3206081271, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
11:12:49.015      41   {TCP:13, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   TCP        TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49413, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1361088072, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
11:12:49.019      42   {IPv4:6}         111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   ICMP       ICMP:Echo Request Message, From 111.11.11.111 To 65.55.74.144
11:12:50.769      45   {IPv4:6}         111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   ICMP       ICMP:Echo Request Message, From 111.11.11.111 To 65.55.74.144
11:12:51.014 46 {TCP:12, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #40]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49412, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=3206081271, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192 11:12:52.015 47 {TCP:13, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #41]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49413, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1361088072, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 819211:12:52.771      48   {TCP:14, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111    data.sn1-1.database.windows.net   TCP        TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49414, DstPort=NETBIOS Session Service(139), PayloadLen=0, Seq=265110652, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
11:12:55.771 49 {TCP:14, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #48]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49414, DstPort=NETBIOS Session Service(139), PayloadLen=0, Seq=265110652, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192 11:12:57.021 52 {TCP:12, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #40]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49412, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=3206081271, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192 11:12:58.016 53 {TCP:13, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #41]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49413, DstPort=Microsoft-DS(445), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1361088072, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192 11:13:01.771 56 {TCP:14, IPv4:6} 111.11.11.111 data.sn1-1.database.windows.net TCP TCP:[SynReTransmit #48]Flags=......S., SrcPort=49414, DstPort=NETBIOS Session Service(139), PayloadLen=0, Seq=265110652, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x8 ) = 8192
```

Here we can see that the client is trying to establish a connection to SQL Database and keeps retransmitting three times and fails

Snippet of trace from a successful connection:

```
14:50:01.512      847  SQLCMD.EXE  {TCP:428, IPv4:427}  99.99.999.99      157.54.118.18    TCP        TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=13415, DstPort=1433, PayloadLen=0, Seq=4009972475, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x2 ) = 8192
14:50:01.515      848  SQLCMD.EXE  {TCP:428, IPv4:427}  157.54.118.18     99.99.999.99     TCP        TCP:Flags=...A..S., SrcPort=1433, DstPort=13415, PayloadLen=0, Seq=2117383693, Ack=4009972476, Win=8192 ( Scale factor not supported ) = 8192
14:50:01.516      849  SQLCMD.EXE  {TCP:428, IPv4:427}  99.99.999.99      157.54.118.18    TCP        TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=13415, DstPort=1433, PayloadLen=0, Seq=4009972476, Ack=2117383694, Win=17040 (scale factor 0x0) = 17040
```

The above snippet represents a successful three-way handshake.